# Android 4.4.x - block software access for user

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, multi-user

I want to setup as "Admin" the tablet and like to have an "User", who don't has access to the setting and/or Google Play. It means, I want to ban some features and software access.

Maybe for this step I need a setting like multipe user accounts. How can I setup this user group?

Comment: What you're looking for is called "restricted profile". See e.g. [How do you configure a Nexus 7/10 for family use](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34724/16575) (Peanut's answer explains it quite nicely), and check our [other questions on "restricted profiles"](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=restricted+profile+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) (currently 10, so shouldn't be that hard to do :)